# $.post doesn't work on locally deployed site

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, post, webforms

I recently "converted" an HTML website to web forms. By convert, I mean I opened the website in Visual Studio 2010, added a web.config file to allow HttpPost protocol, and called it converted. However, my form doesn't want to post to my .aspx page. What am I missing? When I build the app, there is no binary created to deploy to my local IIS (7.5 on Windows 7)

```
<form name="register2" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Then my $.post is in my $(function() {...

```
$('form[name="register2"]').submit(function () {
    var $registerForm2 = $('form[name="register2"]');
    if ($registerForm2.valid()) {
        $.post({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'CreateAccount.aspx',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        });
    } else { //do validation
        $registerForm2.validate();
    }
});
```

When I submit the form, Chrome tells me the request URL is `URL:http://localhost/mysite/[object%20Object]` and receives error code 404. The page `CreateAccount.aspx` does exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the problem now.  the `$.post()` method doesn't support taking an options object as a parameter.

from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

so change your code to be:

```
 $.post( 'CreateAccount.aspx', $(this).serialize() );
```

and give that a try.

Comment: you win, i got the post i expected. woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the extension of your pages to .aspx so the ASP.NET runtime will process it.  You will also need the `<%@ Page %>` directive at the top of the page to indicate the page should be compiled.

Also, you will need to add `runat="server"` to your FORM tag.

Try adding a new WebForm page to the project to see how it gets set up by default, and verify that that works.

Comment: I added page directive and renamed to .aspx `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>`. Does it matter that this page is a facebox popup? I added the `runat="server"` attribute to the form and it does 2 things different: does *not* render the name attribute, and *does* render an id of `ctl100`. I added an id attribute and changed the `submit` function to identify the form by id, but it seems to post the same. Something wrong with the page directive?

Comment: right. ASP.NET automatically generates ID's for you, which causes some pain when using jQuery.  I try to use classes to identify DOM elements.  It seems like for some reason, jQuery is using the wrong URL to submit the request to.  I would put a button the form and the only thing it does is call the `$.post()` code, and serialize the form instead of 'this'.  that might tell us something.

Comment: No such luck with a button or specifically calling .post with it. The markup for the Facebox div's is in a separate file from the "parent" file. The parent is `index.html` and now the child page is `reg.aspx`. Do you think that matters?